# Can I create Google Doc using template and merge fields using API endpoints instead of using client?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-developers-console

I have an existing template Google Doc with merge fields like {{First Name}} and I want to create a document using that template and fill the merge fields using values in javascript. Can I achieve this using the API endpoints instead of the client SDK or library?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I have an existing template Google Doc with merge fields like {{First Name}} and I want to create a document using that template and fill the merge fields using values in javascript.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: I want to create a Google Doc using a template and fill the merge fields using the Doc API endpoints.